Format for Dynamic IQueryable with Strings and Dates
I'm unsure of the correct format to use string and date as variables in a dynamic IQueryable. With numbers, even though they are passed as strings, it works correctly. However, if I use strings or dates, it breaks the query without errors; it just hangs the application. I'm sure I'm missing quotes, but I can't get the format correctly.
This is my code:
string userFilter = string.Empty;
string var1 = "3";
string var2 = "54";
string var3 = "Doe, John";
DateTime var4 = DateTime.Now();

IQueryable<MyClass> query = await _context.Table.GetData();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(var1)) 
{
    userFilter = " column1 == " + var1 + " &&"; 
}; //This works

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(var2)) 
{
    userFilter = userFilter + " column2 == " + var2 + " &&"; 
}; //This works

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(var3)) 
{
    userFilter = userFilter + " column3 == \"" + var3 + "\" &&"; 
}; //Works

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(var4)) 
{
    userFilter = userFilter + " column4 == " + var4 + " &&"; 
}; //Doesn't work

userFilter = userFilter.TrimEnd('&');
query = query.Where(userFilter);

var myData = query.ToList();  

The first two 'if' work correctly, or any with numbers as strings, but actual strings or dates do not. What am I missing?
Thank you!

Is there a reason you can't use strongly-typed Expression<Func<>>-based Linq methods? I don't see how DynamicLinq's String-based expressions are helping you out here...

@Dai To be honest, it's just easier for me to do it this way. I did figure out how to handle the strings, still need help with the dates.

I might suggest using yourDateTimeValue.ToString( "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ) - the "o" format-string is for "round-trip" which means no loss of precision and it always renders to an ISO 8601 / RFC 3339 format which is unambiguous and most systems accept as-is - I assume you'll need delimiting quotes or similar though.

Please share exactly what Linq/IQueryable library you're using that has these String-based Linq methods - I don't recognize it, sorry.

@Dai using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;

@Dai, originally it was Redmond's creature https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I eat my words :)

If you look at userFilter's value you should see the problem with var4 is you are building a query string that contains an unquoted date string. But as @Dai says you would be better to use a non culture specific date format. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/AFPWru for a working example and I've also included the same query using dynamic linq with parameters (which is better, but still produces similar sql) and if you know the column names, the same query without using dynamic linq which is better still as it will generate the best sql.

@sgmoore
The first thing I tried before posting my question was using "" + ... + "". I also tried using parameters. In both cases, I get "Error Number:241,State:1,Class:16". So I check what the SQL being generated looks like and is as follows: SELECT * From MyTable AS [d] WHERE [d].[MyDate] = '2024-07-01T00:00:00.0000000' I checked in the db - it doesn't like that date format. But based on your recommendations, I was able to modify the code and get it to work. Thanks.

The System.Linq.Dynamic.Core library uses its own syntax for DateTime values that resembles ctor calls, like so:
context.Customers.Where("DateTimeProperty >= DateTime(2024,8,16,18,33,0)").ToList();

...but it's a better idea to use parameters, which have the form @<n>, where <n> is an integer:
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
context.Customers.Where("DateTimeProperty >= @0", now).ToList();


// Protip: For greater readability, define this extension method:
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static Boolean IsSet( [NotNullWhen(true)] this String? s ) => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( s );
}

//

String   var1 = "3";
String   var2 = "54";
String   var3 = "Doe, John";
DateTime var4 = DateTime.UtcNow();

IQueryable<MyClass> query = await _context.Table.GetData();

////////
if( var1.IsSet() ) query = query.Where( "column1 == @0", var1 );
if( var2.IsSet() ) query = query.Where( "column2 == @0", var2 );
if( var3.IsSet() ) query = query.Where( "column3 == @0", var3 );
                   query = query.Where( "column4 == @0", var4 );
////////

var myData = query.ToList();

The above query = query.Where(...) statements will be combined as AND terms. Whereas if you want OR logic you can't use PredicateBuilder.Or because these aren't Func<T,Boolean> or Expression<Func<>> methods, but we can hack-it with .Union:
(Untested, YMMV)
String   var1 = "3";
String   var2 = "54";
String   var3 = "Doe, John";
DateTime var4 = DateTime.UtcNow();

IQueryable<MyClass> q = await _context.Table.GetData();

IQueryable<MyClass> u = q.Where( "1 = 0" ); // <-- This always-false term makes it less-awkward.

////////
if( var1.IsSet() ) u = u.Union( q.Where( "column1 == @0", var1 ) );
if( var2.IsSet() ) u = u.Union( q.Where( "column2 == @0", var2 ) );
if( var3.IsSet() ) u = u.Union( q.Where( "column3 == @0", var3 ) );
                   u = u.Union( q.Where( "column4 == @0", var4 ) );
////////

var myData = u.ToList();


Hi @Dai
Thank you for taking the time to write the code.
I figured out how to query with Ling Dynamic without the application hanging, so it compiles and executes; however, I get an error. Which is the same error I'm getting with your code:
Error Number:241,State:1,Class:16
It's a date conversion error. I tried formatting the date in 50 different ways, and the app hangs again with no return error or keeps returning the same error.
